# Using JSON in saved search formula Netsuite

Tags: formula, netsuite, saved-searches

How to get value from JSON in Case Formula Netsuite from a free-form text field

For example, if we have a field  with ID `custcol_test` and it has a Json:

```
{"a": "testa"}
```

When we print the formula in a formula text column like below

```
{custcol_test}
```

It prints the JSON but we need the value `testa` from JSON based on the key `a`

Answer (score 0):

```sql
REGEXP_SUBSTR({custcol_test}, '"a":"(.+?)"', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
```

Replace the `"a"` with whatever key of which you'd like the value.

Example: If your key was 'test', then you'd put `"test"` like this:

```sql
REGEXP_SUBSTR({custcol_test}, '"test":"(.+?)"', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
```

This will only work if your field contains valid JSON.

[REGEXP_SUBSTR Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html)